# Add a div on the left side of a any page

Tags: javascript, html, css, plugins

I developing a plugin and want to add on any page a div on the left side, like a console.
I saw CSS styles, but testing the plugin on greasymonkey not always show me the div, how can i do?

The CSS code that I'm using is this:

```
var div_console = document.createElement("div");
div_consola.id = "div_consola";
div_consola.style.cssText = "overflow:scroll;
z-index:300;position:fixed;left:0px; width: auto; 
height: 100%;  border: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
vertical-align: middle;   background:  #ffdab9;text-align: center;";
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.appendChild(div_consola);
```

So, when loading any page I add with Javascript this div and then populate with data.

Any help?

Thank you!!

Comment: You stated, "not always show me the div"... What happens?  any errors?

Comment: Not errors, its depend on the page DOM, so the div is appended elsewhere, I try to append the div at first, the first node on body, but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

div_consola.id = "div_consola";

div.setAttribute("id", "div_consola"); <------ Try using setAttribute to set Id.

EDIT:
Using same Id name and variable name is also one of the issue.
When I changed the variable name in your code, it worked fine.

var div_consola = document.createElement("div");
var div = document.createElement("div"); <------ variable name changed

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. You have typos in the variable name. I assume you mean `div_console` and not `div_consola`
2. You are assuming that a z-index of 300 will suffice, which may or may not be true. A page could choose to implement a z-index of 301.

Is the rest of your css being applied to the div you wish to affect?

Comment: yeah, it was a typo, and i put z-index just for now. The things is that i want to do is like an iframe on the left side, so the page that loads have to move to the right, its that even posible?

Comment: Of course it is, you can position and manipulate the DOM elements as you wish. Take a look at these examples: [Sidebar Transitions](http://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/)

Comment: Thanks sabhiram, i am looking "reveal" example, i'm going to take a look on that. The only difference is that i have to create all with javascript and on any page ( or almost any :) ). regards!

Comment: Right, what you see there is relying on CSS classes being added to the div. You just have to do the same with pure JS :)

Comment: i had to wrap the body content, here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/B34r8/. If anyone knows if i can do this without the wrapping, please let me know. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified

```
overflow: scroll;
width: auto;
```

Depend of your browser, maybe your div have an undefined size and the scrollbar which pop hide your div.
That's what happened to me when I tried your code on jsFiddle.

Here is the result when I change it to

```
overflow : hidden;
width: 50px;
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B34r8/)

Edit : If it doesn't resolve your problem, could you please precise the conditions (browser, etc) when it doesn't work ?

Comment: I, thanks for the reply, i am trying this with greasemonkey and it doesn't work. Its put the div at any place.

Comment: var div_console = document.createElement("div");
div_console.id = "div_console";
div_console.style.cssText = "z-index:300;position:fixed; overflow: hidden; left:0px; width: 50px; height: 100%;border: solid 1px #e1e1e1;vertical-align: middle; background:  #ffdab9;text-align: center;";
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.appendChild(div_console);